# SignalR SSE handshake fails

Tags: signalr, angular6, windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

Hosting a ASP.Net Core 2.1 webapi and an Angular 6 webapp on "Windows Server 2008 R2" under the same domain name but different ports (:81 and :80 respectively); not contained within the same folder.

According to [this article](https://kevgriffin.com/signalr-transports-explained/), SSE is the (standard) fallback when Websockets are unavailable, which is expected since the server doesn't support Websockets as they were introduced in IIS 8.0 ([server is IIS 7.5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/224609/how-to-obtain-versions-of-internet-information-server-iis))

In development everything works perfectly. However, after publishing, the browser console reports the following after 15 seconds (suspiciously the default "HandshakeTimeout" time).

```
> Information: SSE connected to http://my.website.com:81/notify?id=kaSkcGUjcZD4ylJAC7B70A
> Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled.'.
> Error: Not Found
```

The Startup.cs is currently setup as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.AddCors(o => {
        o.AddPolicy("Limited", builder => builder
            .WithOrigins("http://my.website.com") // .AllowAnyOrigin() also tested and worked
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
        );
    });
    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database"));
    });
}

public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostingEnvironment env,
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseCors("Limited");
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseSignalR(routes => routes.MapHub<NotifyHub>("/notify"));
}
```

With the SignalR Hub being almost empty (event pushing is handled elsewhere):

```
public class NotifyHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

The Angular service is setup as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HubConnection } from '@aspnet/signalr';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RefreshService {
  private connection: HubConnection;
  public timestamp = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
    this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(http://my.website.com:81/notify)
      .build();

    this.connection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        this.connection.on('Message', data => {
          // Do Work
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
  }
}
```

All NuGet packages are up to date (v2.1.1 for everything but Microsoft.NETCore.App which is v2.1.0) and using v1.0.2 (the latest) [ASP.NET SignalR NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr) -- so the server- and client-side SignalRs are the same.

Using a static IP address I was able to get the app to connect to a locally published API (but running IIS 10.0).

Is there something I am missing? A lot of the technologies are pretty new, but I don't yet want to assume there's something wrong with them.

Comment: did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @Esen Unfortunately not

Comment: I disabled Kaspersky firewall & windows firewall on both the web server and the client and it started working. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is still facing this issue, I solved it by configuring IIS 8.0 WebSocket Protocol Support on IIS.

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support)